# am Lebanese citizen and my grandfather served in the French army in second world war time with proofed documents , can i have French citizenship?

Tags: france

I am Lebanese  citizen and my grandfather served in the French army in second world war time with proofed documents , can i have French citizenship ?

Comment: What are "proofed documents?"

Comment: @Elie You give very little background information in your question. It may help you to get a better answer(s) if you read the proposed duplicate and edit your question to include more details, for example what do you mean by ‘proofed documents’? What was your grandfather’s nationality? And do you have any other claim to French citizenship other than the one you’ve mentioned (which on the face of it, doesn’t appear to be a valid claim).

Comment: Hi , my grandfather was Lebanese as well, he served in the french Army during world war 2 (i meant  i have a document that  confirm his serves ) , he did not get a french cictizenship at that time, so my question is that  can we ask for it ?